# Python subprocess.Popen() failed

Tags: python

I am trying to execute this command but it fails:

```
cmdp = ("ps --ppid 1 -f | grep interactive > test.out")
sp = subprocess.Popen(cmdp, shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
name, err = sp.communicate()
rc = sp.wait()
```

rc gets returned as **1** and `test.out` is not created

If I run `ps --ppid 1 -f | grep interactive > test.out` in the terminal, it works fine and `test.out` gets created.

Comment: I don't believe that is the correct way of calling Popen.  You're trying to stuff two commands in there (`ps` and `grep`), but Popen only accepts a single command.  Also you have to pass each argument as separate components in a list (i.e. `['ps', '--ppid', '1', '-f']`, not as a string.

Comment: As it is, you're asking Popen to execute a single command with the literal full name `ps --ppid 1 -f | grep interactive > test.out`, which of course does not exist.

Comment: Ok, I try the following:   cmdp = "grep interactive test.out", still not working

Comment: @JohnGordon with `shell=True`, there is no problem with passing an arbitrary shell command as the first argument.

Comment: Actually Popen can execute multiple commands in a single string. I did figure out why rc is return as 1 sometimes. If the ppid 1 exist, then rc return 0, otherwise return 1.